# Help Computing integral of continuous function

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Consider the Dirichlet function $F:R \rightarrow R$ given by

$f(x):=\begin{cases} x &\text{if } x < 1 ,  \\{}\\ x+1 &\text{if } 1<= x <= 2,  \\{}\\ -x+5 &\text{if } 2<x .\end{cases}$

Then $f$ is continuous and integrable but how can I compute $\int_{0}^{5} f(x) dx$?

Comment: by subdividing the range of integration into three intervals and using $\int_a^b = \int_a^c + \int_c^b$

Comment: It could be from [0,1],[1,2] and[2,5]?

Comment: @Knight Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, $f(x)$ as shown is not continuous (but that makes no big difference).

An alternative method (although the suggestion by @Thomas is the right way to approach such problems in general):

$f(x)$ is piecewise linear on uniform intervals $(0,1), (1,2), \ldots (4,5)$.  For any such function, breaking the function into trapezoids gives an exact result. So the answer will be
$$
\frac12\left[ f(0^+) + f(1^-)+f(1^+) + f(2^-)+f(2^+)+ f(3^-)+f(3^+)+ f(4^-)+f(4^+) f(5^-)\right]= \frac12\left[   0+1+2+3+3+2+2+1+1+0\right]= \frac{15}{2}
$$

If $f(x)$ were continuous, this would be precisely the trapezoid rule for integration, which is exact for functions that are piecewise linear on uniform intervals.